How to trigger a function in Outlook web-based addin from OnMessageSend event?
I have a function, showSendingState() in taskpane code which should change the whole UI of the taskpane to show that it is sending and some other stuff. It needs to be in the taskpane and not in an event handler.
So after user clicks Send, I would like this function to run.
Is it possible?

The best way that I can think of right now is to implement a flag and polling mechanism whereby a function in the taskpane will poll the customProperties of the mailItem periodically for a flag set when OnMessageSend is triggered. If found, it will run the showSendingState() function.
Another way is to register a RecipientsChanged event handler in taskpane and set the Bcc in OnMessageSend event. But this will require a change in the data of the mail and saving it.
If there is an event that can be triggered in OnMessageSend event handler that doesn't require changing the data of the mail, that would be most ideal.

Yes, this can be accomplished. As you suggested, the sending piece is sandboxed in an event-based portion of the add-in while the task pane runs in a different context.
We can use Office.context.mailbox.item?.sessionData https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.sessiondata?view=outlook-js-preview to set a flag on the event side and then the task pane can poll the session data to infer whether the item is sending.
In the taskpane it would need to poll the sessionData in an interval as you cannot subscribe to the sessionData changing with a callback function.

May I know what's the advantage of polling sessionData instead of customProperties?

Your requirements were just to set a flag to trigger a state in the compose view and you didn't want to change the mail message. So session data fits your requirements perfectly. If you use custom properties the flag will be saved to the item and available in read view. Not the end of the world, but why use custom properties if you don't need to?

Ah I see, so it's just a case of using the right tool for the job. Thanks!
